# Max Query in SQL 2008

Tags: sql

I have created a query to provide me with the max of a number associated with an account. For example:

- Account,  Number
- 1234,       8
- 7891,       5
- 4245,       12

I want to add more columns like State and City. When I do this I recieve an error "Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause".

I am not sure how to solve this error, any help?

Sorry for the formating i am not sure how to post this correctly.

Comment: The error message is clear add the new columns in the group by if they dont have an aggregate function.

Comment: You forgot to show us the problematic query...

Comment: I would suggest some basic SQL tutorial

Answer (score 2):

For every column you add to select list, add it to group by clause. You're already grouping by account number, so your statement will look like

```
select account, max(number), city, state from <table> group by account, city, state
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your initial request. The pb seems to be on the SELECT that you made, which is grouping lines, and if you add columns in your result they must be listed in the "group by" line

Answer (score 0):

If you know the values are all the same for a given account, you can also wrap them in `min()` or `max()`:

```
select account, max(number), min(city) as city, min(state) as state
from table t
group by account;
```